# Append string in front of or behind the text and create new variable in Angular 2 TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have an array of key-value pairs.

```
let values= [
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": ""
];
```

I need another array once the user has interacted with the form.

```
let values= [
    "firstname_MODIFIED": true,
    "lastname_MODIFIED": false
];
```

Since everything is dynamic, so once user has interacted with "lastname", I will get that key and I need to append "_MODIFIED" at the end to create new key.

```
lastname -> lastname_MODIFIED
<uniqueKey> -> <uniqueKey>_MODIFIED
```

Then I'd use new array elements in my HTML form.

```
<span ngIf="values.firstname_MODIFIED">First name is modified.</span>
<span ngIf="values.lastname_MODIFIED">Last name is modified.</span>
```

Something like this I should able to generate in TS file.

```
let firstname_MODIFIED = true;
let lastname_MODIFIED = false;
let <uniqueKey>_MODIFIED = <ifuser changed the value>
```

Comment: you question is not clear but if you want to define a variable in view you can have like <span #firstName_MODIFIED ngIf="firstName_MODIFIED">Last name is modified.</span>

Comment: I have added more details. Please let me know if the issue is still unclear.

Comment: In angular, when you have a template drive form your have properties like ng-touch, ng-pristine.. (see https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel) and when you have a reactive form touche or pristine (see https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#inspect-formcontrol-properties). You can compare two variables like < span ngIf="oldvalues.firstname==values.firstname" >. This aproach help you to avoid problems when the script will be uglifly